# Storing id of each article tag

Tags: javascript, php, html

Given below is a snippet of my PHP code. I am creating an HTML page which displays a bunch of movies with their titles and images. All the necessary credentials of the movie are returned from my database in `$row`. The problem is thatI need a local link on this line :

```
<p> <a href = "#" > I have already seen this movie </a></p>
```

and need to send my appropriate movie id (not the last movie id which will be present in `$movieid` after the while loop) to a function where I can add the movie to a table in my database. Could someone help me with this?

```
                <?php
                    $movieid ="";
                    $title ="";
                    $photoURL ="";
                    $runtime ="";

                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval2, MYSQL_ASSOC))
                        {
                             $movieid =  $row['movieId'];
                             $title =  $row['title'];
                             $photoURL =  $row['photoURL'];
                             $runtime =  $row['runtime'];

                        ?>             
                    <article>
                        <a class="thumbnail"  href= <?php print $photoURL; ?>><img src=<?php print $photoURL; ?> alt="" /></a>
                        <h2 text-align: center> <?php print $title; ?> </h2>
                        <h3> RUNTIME = <?php print $runtime; ?> minutes</h3>
                        <p> <a href = "#" > I have already seen this movie </a></p>

                    </article> <?php
                        }
                ?>

            <!-- Footer -->
                <footer id="footer">
                    <ul class="copyright">
                        <li>&copy; SANS-CIS550-2015.</li>
                    </ul>
                </footer>
```

Comment: Your loop doesn't end until after the `</article>` tag, so why can't you use `$movieid`?

Comment: Where exactly in your snippet do you use `$movieid` ? _italic_ and need to send my appropriate movie id (not the last movie id which will be present in $movieid after the while loop) to a function where I can add the movie to a table in my database _italic_ , where is this function? How do you pass the movieid to this function? On what event? Please edit your question and add all relevant details.

Answer (score 0):

In the line with `<php print $runtime; ?> you can access ´$runtime`because that part of the code is still within the `while`-loop. That loop contains everything from the `{` until the closing `}` - so you can safely refer to  `$movieid` and build the appropriate href, there's no problem!